# To use multivariate linear regression with a polynomial hypothesis or logistic regression with multiple classes?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

I was just wondering as to the specific scenarios one would use multivariate linear regression to predict an output against something like logistic regression with multiple classes. Would it be primarily based on how logistic regression offers the probabilities for an outcome? Which cases is each one the best in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multivariate regression is used when there are multiple dependent variables.

Multionial logistic regression is used when there is one dependent variable with more than two levels that are not ordinal.